# Choosing energy levels for finding quantum numbers

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, atomic-structure

When an element has multiple energy levels (i.e Titanium has $(Ar)3d^24s^2$), what energy level do we use to find the quantum numbers? Is it generally assumed the LAST energy level is used? or is it the orbital that has the highest energy?

Comment: Review the guide [How to ask](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Asking FAQs](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help/asking) to prevent clarification requests, objections,  down-voting or closure.

Answer (score 0):

Each orbital has its own set of quantum numbers. Without external fields,  each orbital group has its own energy level, otherwise each orbital. It is your choice, for which orbital you want to know it's quantum numbers and energy.

Comment: Right. Thing is, we had a midterm on this and it wasnt specified on what orbital to compute the Q.N from. Was there an underlying assumption I missed?

Comment: You can always provide the answer for multiple choices. // **A** asking **B** *"Why did **C** say **X**?"* does not usually provide a satisfactory answer if **C** had multiple valid choices. As **B** does not usually know why **C** did/said so either,  **A** should ask **C** .